# Is there a way to request deletion of own question?

Tags: discussion

Yes, I know you can delete it, and I know you can flag your own post. But with deleting your own post, there's a chance that you might get question restricted, and with flagging the mods might think that you're crazy to ask to delete your own question when you can delete it yourself.

Now, I also know that the question may help other people for whatever reason, but say it doesn't. Say that I asked an extremely obvious question, like trying to get a string from a double or something, and want it deleted. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can ask being removed from a post as author. But not just because you asked an obvious question.

Comment: Your question is not really well organized here.  It almost sounds like you are trying to have a conversation.  Just ask you question... type it out as if you were writing an email to your boss.  You will find your will get a much more positive response.  From reading this, it feels like you have a question that you didn't actually ask, so if I am reading that correct, just ask the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aha, I understood you ;-). You are afraid of being banned from asking because of deleting your own question? First of all, a single question can't trigger a ban. Second, it doesn't matter, who deletes your question (you, mod, or 3 users with 10k+ reps), the deletion is counted towards the ban anyway.

Comment: You don't really know that deletions count towards the ban... no one does except the devs.  It has never really been documented that they contribute towards the ban in a meaningful way.  What we do know is that deletion does not keep the question from contributing to the ban.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I do know :D

Comment: @psubsee2003 my understanding has always been that deletions do factor into bans.

Comment: @Cupcake I'm not saying they don't count.  But anything that says they do count differently is only speculation.  In everything I've read, the SE devs have never taking a strong position on deletions on whether they count more or not.  The closest I have seen is a recent post by Shog (I cant find the reference at the moment) that deletions after a long time do not matter and deletions immediately after an answer will hurt badly... but beyond that, there isn't enough detail to make a conclusive statement

Comment: @psubsee2003 http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267448/2963652 (point 2)

Comment: @nicael last time I checked ChrisF was only a moderator and not a developer.  And he never said "deletions count towards the ban".  It only said a post will count not matter who deletes it.  There is a slight difference.  I'm not disputing your point, only trying to clarify a misconception that deletions count more towards the post ban.